# C++ alias template (typedef) with concepts?

Tags: c++, typedef, using, c++-concepts, c++20

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4553.pdf

gcc6: -fconcepts

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept bool String = requires(T s)
{
    { s.clear() } -> void;
    // etc.
};

void print(const String& message);
//void print(Str message); // I want Str = const String&

void test()
{
  std::string str;
  print(str);
}
```

Is there any way to declare `Str` as `const String&`?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend hiding things like that. If I see a parameter with type `Str` I will assume that it creates a copy rather than secretly taking a reference.

Comment: This code is just an example. I want to know if it could be done, not whether this particular example makes any sense.

Comment: You could do something like `template <String T> using Str = const T&;`, but then you don't get the deduction.

Comment: This makes no sense. It will not allow to declare abbreviated template "void print(Str message);" as requested.

Comment: That's why I said you don't get the deduction with methods like that. You need the template deduction to carry out the pattern matching on `const T&`.

Comment: I'd say that the only way is `#define Str const String&`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to declare `Str` as `const String&`?

No. And moreover, you don't want that anyway. Concepts are about adding constraints to types. So if you want to constraint `print` to take something that models `String`, you can do that:

```
template <typename T> requires String<T> void print(T const&); // requires-clause
template <String T> void print(T const&); // partial-concept-id
void print(String auto const&); // probably what C++20 will allow
```

But the constraint and the value category are orthogonal. You could take `String` by value:

```
void print(String auto);
```

you could take a `String` by forwarding reference:

```
void print(String auto&&);
```

These are all separate options from the "I want a `String`" aspect. You can't really group those together.

---

The best you could do is:

```
template <String T> using Str = T const&;
template <typename T> void print(Str<T>); // silently a const&
```

or

```
template <typename T> using CR = T const&;
template <String T> void print(CR<T>); // silently a const&
```

That works. For some definition of works. But like... don't do that. The fact that a function takes a `const&` as opposed to a value is very important visual information, don't just hide it.